# Sharepoint 2007: Multi tiered top navigation

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I have a site within a site and would like to see this site appear as a drop down menu in the top menu bar (ID="TopNavigationMenu"). In the default.master page I have edited the following:
    StaticDisplayLevels="2"
    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3"
In the Menu Navigation I added the top site to the global navigation area, but it doesn't display the sub sites on the top menu drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the option 'show subsites' in the navigation settings is checked for both your site as your subsite.

Comment: Show sub sites IS checked. As I mentioned before, I added the site to the global navigation but it is not showing any subsites.